# Symfony2 Get controller which called service in service

Tags: symfony

I created a few custom loggers to help with development. However, I was wondering if there was any way to see which controller called the relevant function which made the log entry?

I've heard kernel.request contains the relevant info but I can't figure out how to obtain it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get a stack trace from the Exception object with `getTrace` or `getTraceAsString` (http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/exception.gettraceasstring.php) which should give you which controller your service was called from.

Comment: I don't have an exception though, just something I want to log.